# Are there characters (like . + =) that are prefixed to the expression &nbsp;?

Tags: html, python-3.x

I am learning python and I am using the German textbook: Einstieg in Python (in English Beginning Python) from Thomas Theis. In this book there is a chapter about setting up a webserver. In a code example (more precisely a .cgi file) I do not understand the code shown below.

I have intensively searched in Google and some other textbook. But I have not found an answer.

```
    ..
    # table line
            print("<tr>")
            print("<td>&nbsp;" + str(aufgabe+1)
                  + ".&nbsp;</td>")
            print("<td>&nbsp;" + str(a) + "&nbsp;</td>")
            print("<td>&nbsp;+&nbsp;</td>")
            print("<td>&nbsp;" + str(b) + "&nbsp;</td>")
            print("<td>&nbsp;=&nbsp;</td>")
            print("<td><input name='ein" + str(aufgabe)
                  + "' size='12'></td>")
            print("</tr>")
...
```

I understand the function of `&nbsp;` ( non blocking space), but I  do not understand the meaning of `.&nbsp;` , `+&nbsp;` and `=&nbsp;` i. e. the meaning of the prefixed `.` `+` `=`
The code is doing well, so I think that this is not a printing error.
Pleas excuse my English, but I am not a native speaker of the English language.

Answer (score 0):

`+&nbsp;` is just a `+`  followed by a nonbreaking space. There is nothing special about it, it is like `+a` where `+` is followed by `a`, the only difference is that `&nbsp;` represents one escaped character.

The `&` in html marks the beginning of an escaped character and the `;` marks the end of that. Those escaped chars could be named like `nbsp`, `lt`, `gt`, `amp`, ... or could be hexadecimal numeric character reference like `#xA0`.

Answer (score 0):

`&nbsp;` is simply a non-breaking space: . They are not prefixed as such; `.&nbsp;` would simply just appear as `.` followed by a .

These must be escaped in HTML as well as other "special" characters, e.g.: `&lt;` = `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Those characters have no special meanings and are just part of the markup's text content (IOW those are plain literals "+", "." etc characters).

Comment: In consequence, what is the meaning of . + = in this code?

Comment: @user200179 as I said: they have absolutely no meaning (wrt: code), they are just plain strings.  Have you looked at the result ? Did you try rendering it in your browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the prompt answers. 
Now I know the answer to my question. The table is part of the calculation task given in this textbook. The author wanted to get the output:
1**.**      21 **+** 16 **=** 39 (Sorry, but . could not be displayed in bold font, so it is shown as  ** .**  instead).
Thank You very much for your effort and your input to me!